# Django scaling beginner advice / resources

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web-applications, architecture

I am a relatively new to Django web development with about one year of experience with programming as a whole, and a few months less with Django web development.

With two friends we came up with a business idea, and we are developing that. And even though I (I am the person programming the most, together with one more experienced friend guiding me) am quite new to this, I would like to make this project a success.

So, to come to the point, I would like to set up the project in such a way that the project could handle large loads with grace, in the future. I am thinking about a worldwide platform, and so, a very large number of visitors.

We are using Django Rest Framework to build an API which serves a ReactJS powered front-end, using PostgreSQL as our database.

Short description of application:
The web application will be a platform where (registered) users will be able to manage their storage. Other users (registered or not) will be able to search within the total storage. It will not be a website that handles a lot of media (images, videos). And their will not be a lot of different categories of items to store. I can give more details if needed.

What advice would you advice a beginner who wants to learn about setting up a project in such a way that it is capable of scaling. Some beginner friendly resources (courses, books, websites, etc.) would also be great.

Since the resources we have are limited (one beginner doing the main programming), I would like to not dive into too much of theory, since I want a good balance between study and actual production. It would be nice if you could keep that in mind when answering the question.

I am sure that are a lot of other beginners in Django programming for who'm the answers to this question could be very beneficial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found two interesting articles about Django scaling, and googling "scaling django rest framework" shows some more promising results. I'll be sure to try "scaling django" as well, and see what else I can find.  https://djangobook.com/scaling-django/
https://sanketsaurav.com/lessons-from-scale-django-124f7b16ae0c

Reading the book 'Building maintainable software, Java Edition' has already helped me write code that is easier to understand, test and to reuse.

The goal is to write tests for as much code as possible, this will be started in future sprints (soon). Ideally in future sprints no code will be produced that is not covered by tests.

Also I use 'Two Scoops of Django 1.11' as a guide, this has a lot if helpful information.

I can guess that getting people in our team who are experienced in this area, would be one of the best ways to deal with this. Albeit that at this point this isn't really an option since we don't have the budget. I'll be sure to discuss this topic with more experienced programmers soon at a programming meetup.